# Return X amount of documents for each $in matching query

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm currently trying to query a collection, let's call `Telemetry`, by matching documents on an array:

```
var hardwareIDs = ['A','B','C'];
Telemetry.find({ hardwareID: { $in: hardwareIDs }});
```

Here's an example of what a `Telemetry` record might look like:

```
{
   _id: xxxx,
   insertedAtUTC: xxxx,
   hardwareID: xxxx,
   year: 2016,
   month: 2,
   day: 31,
   hour: 0,
   data: []
}
```

But what I've found difficult to do is get, let's say, **the latest 3 documents** of each matching query. So effectively I'd like to return a cursor that looks similar to this:

```
[
   { insertedAtUTC: 3, hardwareID: "A", ... },
   { insertedAtUTC: 2, hardwareID: "A", ... },
   { insertedAtUTC: 1, hardwareID: "A", ... },
   { insertedAtUTC: 3, hardwareID: "B", ... },
   { insertedAtUTC: 2, hardwareID: "B", ... },
   { insertedAtUTC: 1, hardwareID: "B", ... },
   { insertedAtUTC: 3, hardwareID: "C", ... },
   { insertedAtUTC: 2, hardwareID: "C", ... },
   { insertedAtUTC: 1, hardwareID: "C", ... }
]
```

Any thoughts on how to formulate a MongoDB query to solve this problem?

I've tagged this with `meteor` as I am using MongoDB in MeteorJS. I'm currently trying to publish a lightweight cursor as the `Telemetry` collection is fairly large but I don't think this should have any impact on the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive that by using a mapreduce: emit all hardwareID, than in reduce, sort them by insertedAtUTC.

Further, if you want to filter the projection of fields more, you can apply an aggregate, unwind and do a projection for your documents.
Take a look at my example script.js:

```
use stackoverflow

db.dropDatabase()

db.telemetry.insert(
    [   
        { hardwareID: "C", insertedAtUTC: 2 },
        { hardwareID: "C", insertedAtUTC: 3 },
        { hardwareID: "C", insertedAtUTC: 1 },
        { hardwareID: "A", insertedAtUTC: 1 },
        { hardwareID: "A", insertedAtUTC: 2 },
        { hardwareID: "A", insertedAtUTC: 3 },
        { hardwareID: "B", insertedAtUTC: 3 },
        { hardwareID: "B", insertedAtUTC: 2 },
        { hardwareID: "B", insertedAtUTC: 1 },
        { hardwareID: "X", insertedAtUTC: 2 },
        { hardwareID: "X", insertedAtUTC: 1 }
    ]
)


var hardwareIDs = ['A','B','C'];

var map = function map(){
    emit(this.hardwareID, this);

};

var reduce = function(key, values){
    var sorted_values = values.sort(function(first, second) {
        return second.insertedAtUTC - first.insertedAtUTC;
    }).slice(0,2);
    return {key, sorted_values};
};


db.runCommand({"mapReduce":"telemetry", map:map, reduce:reduce, out:{replace:"telemetry2"}, query:{ hardwareID: { $in: hardwareIDs }}})

var result = db.telemetry2.aggregate(
    [
     { $unwind : {path: '$value.sorted_values' }},
     { $project: {
        _id: '$value.sorted_values._id',
        hardwareID: '$value.sorted_values.hardwareID',
        insertedAtUTC: '$value.sorted_values.insertedAtUTC'
        } 
     }
    ]
);

while(result.hasNext()){
    printjson(result.next());
}
```

You can run the script in console by

```
mongo < script.js
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer as this definitely answers the question but unfortunately the output using mapReduce in the Meteor framework returns some unexpected results. Will troubleshoot more and post another question if necessary. Thanks for your time!